# Prestashop 1.7: Use CMS page as home page

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to use a CMS page as home page on Prestashop 1.7
My website is naturamed.it
My CMS page is https://www.naturamed.it/p/naturamedit-test-sierologici-tamponi-rapidi-e-test-salivari-covid-19-coronavirus
CMS page ID: 7

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You could use a *.htaccess* redirection or 
override the Prestashop Dispatcher to provide a 301 redirect on the CMS page if source url is the index...

Otherwise you can do it "the clean way" by building a simple module that display the content of that CMS page inside the hook **displayHome()** and exclude any unwanted modules from the index / home page.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! How can i set redirect on htaccess? Or do you have a module that can add CMS content in home page?